# Embedding WireGuard into a Go app on Windows

Tags: go, wireguard

I am writing an application in Go that will use WireGuard tunnels to communicate. I want to embed WireGuard within the application rather than install the separate WireGuard program. I understand that I can use wireguard.dll and tunnel.dll to embed in a general application. But given my app is also written in Go, is this still the right way to go? Or should I be calling go libraries from within the WireGuard-Windows program instead?

The documentation is minimal and is mostly non-Go based. Does this approach still apply in a Go scenario?

Comment: Hi,

Just curious , why would you use tunnels inside an application and not just open  SSL/TLS socket ?

Thanks

Comment: My application is providing a management layer for the wireguard VPN tunnels themselves. i.e. the VPN is for general use by the PC.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [zx2c4 `wireguard-go` module](https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-go/about/), ([`wireguard-windows`](https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-windows/about/) uses `wireguard-go` as a module)

You can see an example in [`main_windows.go`](https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-go/tree/main_windows.go): while `wireguard-windows` remains the full-fledge Wireguard Windows client, this give you an illustration for calling Wireguard from a Go program.